# When does transclusion take place in the compilation/linking process of a directive's setup?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm writing a custom directive that uses transclusion. I need to make modifications to the transcluded DOM content AFTER the transclusion has taken place....would I want to do that in the post-link or in the controller or ... the link...? I don't know where transclusion falls in the order of those things happening, so I don't know how to ensure my JS is executed after the transclusion has taken place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The transclusion takes place during the compilation phase. Angular's `$compile` service goes over the DOM, and if a directive has transclusion enabled, Angular extracts the contents of the element (if `transclude: true`, or the element itself - for `transclude: 'element'`), compiles them, and makes the compiled content available in the transclusion function, bound to the transclusion scope.

So, the order of execution would be:

1. Angular transcludes the contents and compiles it: `compile` functions **of the transcluded content** directives execute
2. `compile` function **of the directive** executes - returns `pre`- and `post`-link functions
3. `controller` function **of the directive** executes
4. `pre`-link function **of the directive** executes
5. `post`-link function **of the directive** executes.

You may decide to execute the `transclude` function in the `post`-link function. As soon as you do,

6. `controller`, `pre`-, and `post`-link functions **of the transcluded content** directives execute

`transclude` function is available at step #3-#5, and when invoked, it provides a fresh copy of the transcluded element to the `cloneAttachFn`, which you provide as a parameter to the `transclude` function:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transclude){
    transclude(scope, function cloneAttachFn(clone){
      // you can do DOM manipulation of the clone instance here
    });
}
```

Note, that the DOM manipulation in the `cloneAttachFn` would apply to an instance of the transcluded DOM - not to the pre-compiled DOM template.